# IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5: Cannot determine embedded database driver

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

Since some months I'm getting a lot of false positives when starting my Spring application in IntelliJ 2017.2.5. When starting it shows the error `Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE`. I just have to give it some additional tries and it will work. Often opening the `appliation.properties` in the IDE also helps (but might be coincidence). This happens to me (Linux) and also a friend working with the same project (Mac). Anyone else experienced that?

Comment: There is similar issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151236. Please try solutions in comments.

Comment: @y.bedrov: Thanks for your hint but sadly it's not helping.

Comment: You are welcome to report new one or attach information about your configuration to the existing issue on YouTrack.

Answer (score 1):

The latest updated of IntelliJ seems to fix the issue: `Bug IDEA-178438 application properties not set when starting Spring Boot service in IDEA` (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178438)

Answer (score 0):

Time to time this problem happens to me. The only thing that resolved to me is a [full rebuild](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178438#comment=27-2527374) of the project on Intellij IDEA:

```
Build > Rebuild Project
```